# Convert Text file that has more than on value to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I tried to convert a text file to a dictionary. The text form was as follows:

```
0 <-> a
1 <-> b
2 <-> cd
3 <-> E
5 <-> f
6 <-> G
7 <-> hij
9 <-> k
```

I tried to read each line of text file then put it in an empty dictionary with certain format:

For example:

```
{'0': {'a'}, '1': {'b'}, '2': {'c', 'd'}, '3': {'e'}, '5': {'f'}, '6': {'g'}, '7': {'h', 'i', 'j'}, '9': {'k'}}
```

I tried:

```
d = {}
with open('txtfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        (key,val) = line.strip().split('<->')
        d[str(key).strip()] = val.strip()

return(d)
```

Then I got:

```
{'0': 'a', '1': 'b', '2': 'cd', '3': 'e', '5': 'f', '6': 'g', '7': 'hij', '9': 'k'}
```

I was tried to split `cd` & `hij` to `{'c', 'd'}` and `{'h','i','j'}`, but I was not able to find a way to do that, and even though I used the strip to remove empty space at the start, and end of each line in the text file, but when I used for loop to check out each key, and value of dictionary there was some empty space between each character.

Comment: The exact expected output is not possible. `{...}` is an unordered set. For example, "cd" may become `{'c','d'}`, but it may also become `{'d','c'}`. If the order is important, you should use lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there, you just need to call `set` on `val.strip()` to convert your string, e.g. `"ab"`, to a set, e.g. `{"a", "b"}`, i.e.:

```
d = {}                                                                          
with open('txtfile.txt') as f:                                                  
    for line in f:                                                              
        key, val = line.strip().split('<->')                                   
        d[key.strip()] = set(val.strip())

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'0': {'a'}, '1': {'b'}, '2': {'d', 'c'}, '3': {'E'}, '5': {'f'}, '6': {'G'}, '7': {'h', 'j', 'i'}, '9': {'k'}}
```